# How do I add multithreading this?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I don't know how to web scrape that much, I wrote this code but it is running really slowly, this code is used to get the search results from a google chrome query. I want to try to add multithreading but I don't really know how. Can somebody tell me how to multithread? Also which function am I supposed to multithread?

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool
# desktop user-agent

def get_listing(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    html = None
    links = None

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        html = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        listing_section = soup.select('#offers_table table > tbody > tr > td > h3 > a')
        links = [link['href'].strip() for link in listing_section]
    return links

def scrapeLinks(query_string):
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"

    query = query_string
    query = query.replace(' ', '+')
    URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query}"

    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        results = []
        for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
            anchors = g.find_all('a')
            if anchors:
                link = anchors[0]['href']
                title = g.find('h3').text
                item = {
                    "title": title,
                    "link": link
                }
                results.append(item)
        return results

def getFirst5Results(query_string):
    list = scrapeLinks(query_string)
    return [list[0]["link"], list[1]["link"], list[2]["link"], list[3]["link"], list[4]["link"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things about multithreading

- You can use it for the code that required network calls. For
  instance, invoking an api.
- When the code would run for a longer
  duration of time, and you want to run the process in the background.
- In the case you've stated the web scraping is a long running tasks,
  as it involves network call to google api and parsing of the results
  after we get the results back. Assuming that you're using
  `scrapeLinks` function for scraping.
  Here's some code :

`import threading 
t1 = threading.Thread(target = scrapeLinks, args = (query_string,) 
t1.start()`

In order to retrieve results from the thread use:
`t1.join()`